# MVC 5 Google Calendar Integration

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-calendar-api

I have a simple MVC5 Application with same users. Now I need (for every single user) create entry in every google calendar. Each user have your calendar in google. Each user use local authentication for login in mvc application. To use google calendar api I need store for each user single credential and use it, or I can enable google mvc authentication and use it? Thanks

Comment: your question is a little unclear to what you have done so far but https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc  FileDataStore handels storing the users credentials.

Comment: you can use Google's OAuth tools to get the user to log into their google account via your application, and then you can send/receive data from their Google Calendar. It's all explained in the Calendar API docs, with examples. There are a few different ways to organise your authentication. But you can't really store user's credentials long-term, because the access tokens will expire. Choose whatever suits your use case. See https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/ and https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/auth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I find this demo project 
https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client-samples/tree/master/Calendar.ASP.NET.MVC5

and this document: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/dotnet

My solutions is per user integration with single google credential. Then using code in demo I can update single user google calendar.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion your application provide following cornerstones:

- user authentification for private calendar access
- with the user authentication you get the user name to create a private folder to store private credential information

Hopefully this helps.

Andreas

https://www.andreasulbricht.de/cctsync/